# Rest Countdown to Next day once target is hit

Tags: javascript, html

**Goal**: Im attempting to create A countdown clock that resets once it hits a certain time. Then counts down to say 1:00pm the next day, and repeats.

Here is the code so far.

```js
if(document.getElementById("countdown")) {
  intTime = function(n, len) {
    var intSeconds = n.toString();
    return (new Array((len - intSeconds.length + 1)).join('0')) + intSeconds;
  };
  
  var timerRunning = setInterval (
    function countDown() {
      var target = 13; // 1:00pm || 13:00hrs
      var now = new Date();
      
      //actual countdown timer
      var intHours = (target - 1) - now.getHours();
      var intMins = 59 - now.getMinutes();
      var intSecs = 59 - now.getSeconds();
      
      //Timer String
      var timeString = intTime(intHours, 2) + ':' + intTime(intMins, 2) + ':' + intTime(intSecs, 2);
      
      if (intHours < 0) intHours = 0;
      if (intMins < 0) intMins = 0;
      if (intSecs < 0) intSecs = 0;
      if (now.getHours() > target) {
          
      }
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = timeString;
     }, 1000
  );
}
```

```html
<p id="timer">Order within <span id="countdown">0</span></p>
```

The count down its self works.
However im really unsure what to put in side this peace of code:

```
      if (now.getHours() > target) {

      }
```

Ive tried adding `now() * 24;` ive tried increasing the target. 
everything Ive tried presents the same result. 
I get a minus and then its counting down again too something in two hours.

I'm Racking my brain and im getting no where, Id appreciate any help that you can give me. Call me an idiot if you want for missing something glaringly obvious.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Changed the var target to empty, then set it in an if statement.

```
 var target;
  var hrs = now.getHours();

  if (hrs >= 14) {
    target = 14 + 24;
  } else {
    target = 14;
  }
```